# I want to insert a load statement in llvm IR file

Tags: insert, llvm

I have llvm IR code like:

```
%0 = load i32* %b, align 4
%mul = mul nsw i32 %0, 1
```

I want to replace second instruction with a load:`%mul = load i32* %0, align4`

so I use following code:

```
new LoadInst(op1, "mul", x);
```

where x is pointer(instruction*) to the instruction I wish to replace, 
Value* op1 = x->getOperand(0);

after this instruction is inserted before x, I erase x(current instruction). When I run it, I get error here. I feel that I am not passing correct arguments.

PS: I am not allowed to use utility class to make changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with what you are doing.

**First**, if this is your target code, it is illegal:

```
%0 = load i32* %b, align 4
%mul = load i32* %0, align 4
```

Since the type of `%0` is `i32`, but in the load you assume it is `i32*`.

**Second**, the proper way to replace one instruction with another is to [use `ReplaceInstWithInst`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/namespacellvm.html#a58cb353f6bb490b0c689f5f2a830414d) (at BasicBlockUtils.h), as it will also update all the users of the old instruction to use the new instruction.

To clarify why your way doesn't work, here's a demonstration (ignoring the type problem):

```
%0 = load i32* %b, align 4
%mul = mul nsw i32 %0, 1
ret i32 %mul
```

Now you run `new LoadInst(op1, "mul", x);` and get:

```
%0 = load i32* %b, align 4
%mul = load i32* %0, align 4
%mul.1 = mul nsw i32 %0, 1
ret i32 %mul.1
```

Why did I rename the second instruction from `%mul` to `%mul.1`? I didn't; both are named `%mul`. But when you print it out the printer will append `.<serial number>` to all instructions that share the same scope and name, to prevent confusion.

Needless to add, after deleting you get this:

```
%0 = load i32* %b, align 4
%mul = load i32* %0, align 4
ret i32 %mul.1
```

And the `ret` is referring to a missing value.

In short, you cannot rely on the instruction name for anything, it's only there to help debugging and to make the textual representation of the IR more readable.

Comment: I understand that I'll have to somehow update the use. (Not allowed to use BasicBlockUtils.h)
But, I was stuck at first step itself. So, I get the type problem but how do I go about correcting that as I want to load %0, so I cannot create a new ptr.

Comment: @rahuL didn't quite understand your clarification. You can only load from a pointer - though you can use `inttoptr` to convert integers to pointers, if you know the integer represents an address.

Comment: using getOperand(0) I get variable %0, but its type is i32, how do I convert it to i32* so I can load value of %0 in mul?(as you suggested in the first problem my way has)

Comment: @rahuL if you just want to use the value, you don't have to load it again - it's already loaded. If you know the value is actually an address and you want to load from there, you can use the `inttoptr` instruction, as I have written above (though a better solution in that case would be to have have `%b` be of type `i32**` instead of `i32*`).